# Compare object selected by user and objects on the db, return objects if match ratio is more than 50%

Tags: database, amazon-dynamodb, backend

i'm sorry if my question is complicated or hard to understand. I'm an junior front-end developer and trying to create an mobile application. Therefore i need to create an database but I have no experience on this. On my plans i need 2 tables. I will try to explain them with an example.

- Table-1 will keep letters of alphabets as string.
- Table-2 will keep random amount of letters in arrays. like;

`[{id:1, letters:[a,b,x,y,q]}, {id:2, letters:{a,b,c} ]`

When users run the app, they will get all the letters from table-1. and will select some of them by checkboxes.

My problem starts right on here. I want to know if i able to send user's selected letters to server and compare that letters with objects on table-2. and return the objects at table-2 if match ratio is higher than 50%.

For example;

- User select a,b,c,d,e,f and press search button
- table-2 has 2 object like `[{id:1, letters:[a,b,c]},{id:2, letters:[a,b,x,y,z]}]`
- user's selection contains all letters of id 1. But contains 2/5(40%) of id 2.
  On this example i want server return the object with id 1.

Can i do it on server side or should i get all objects from server and compare them on app (i don't want to do that because i don't know how much objects will contain on tables).

Which database solution should i use? I started an amazon 12 month trial but i could try another solutions too. but it would be great if I could make it for free at the beginning.

Thank you for read, im waiting for your answers if  that is possible, and which way should i use.

Answer (score 0):

This is definitely doable directly on the server side. You firstly would want to store each letter in the letter list in a separate row per ID for efficient matching.

---

```
create table test.Test(id integer, letter varchar(1), PRIMARY KEY (id,letter));

insert into test.Test values(1,"a");
insert into test.Test values(1,"b");
insert into test.Test values(1,"x");
insert into test.Test values(1,"y");
insert into test.Test values(1,"q");
insert into test.Test values(2,"a");
insert into test.Test values(2,"b");
insert into test.Test values(2,"c");

\\base query that gives you total count by ID
select id,count(letter) as total_length from test.Test group by id;


\\base query that gives you character present by ID
select id,count(letter) as character_present from test.Test where letter in ("a","b","c","d","e") group by id; 


\\query to get the ID from Table Test with more than 50% match
select x.id 
from
(
    select id,count(letter) as total_length from test.Test group by id
) as x
inner join
(
    select id,count(letter) as character_present from test.Test where letter in ("a","b","c","d","e") group by id
)as y on x.id=y.id where character_present/total_length>0.5;


\\query to get all the data from Table Test with more than 50% match
select * from test.Test where id IN
(
    select x.id 
    from
    (
        select id,count(letter) as total_length from test.Test group by id
    ) as x
    inner join
    (
        select id,count(letter) as character_present from test.Test where letter in ("a","b","c","d","e") group by id
    )as y on x.id=y.id where character_present/total_length>0.5;
);
```

---

Output:

2         | a

2         | b

2         | c

---

Of course, this is just one of the way to implement this solution. As you spend more time you can make this more efficient but this should get you started.

Comment: My table data is slightly different from the example you mentioned, so please keep a note of that.

Comment: if i'm not wrong these are sql commands. so i need to practice sql and learn how to create db on amazon aurora. I want to see if someone post another solution and try them. Thank you for your answer, i will accept this as answer when i tried.